# RestSharp ignoring system proxy (for example Fiddler) on .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, fiddler, restsharp, dotnet-httpclient

I want check the http traffic with Fiddler, but no any http traffic captured, my testing codes:

```
private static void ByRestSharp()
{
    var restClient = new RestClient("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com");
    var request = new RestRequest("posts", Method.GET);
    var response = restClient.Get<List<Post>>(request);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} posts return by RestSharp.", response.Data.Count);
}
```

But after I changed to use HttpClient, Fiddler can capture the http traffic, sample codes:

```
private static void ByHttpClient()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"))
    using (var resp = httpClient.SendAsync(req).Result)
    {
        var json = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var users = SimpleJson.SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<List<Post>>(json);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} posts return by HttpClient.", users.Count);
    }
}
```

Is this a issue of RestSharp or Fiddler?

Answer (score 22):

RestSharp supported system proxy until we moved to .NET Standard. Then, we got issues with proxy on .NET Core and then using the system proxy was removed entirely. We have an [issue opened on Github](http://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1043) and you can check the progress there.

However, explicitly setting the proxy should work for full .NET Framework, check [this issue](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1032).

Code from the issue, which is confirmed to be working:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://www.google.com");
client.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);
var req = new RestRequest("/", Method.GET);
var resp = client.Execute(req);
```

**Update 2018-05-31:** RestSharp 106.3 is using the default proxy on .NET Core also, automatically. Tested with Fiddler.

**Update 2022-02-23:** RestSharp 107 has the `Proxy` property moved to `RestClientOptions`:

```
var options = new RestClientOptions("http://www.google.com") {
    Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888)
};
var client = new RestClient(options);
var req = new RestRequest("/");
var resp = await client.ExecuteAsync(req);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The code runs fine, but nothing in Fiddler. Quite sure my Fiddler configuration is pretty basic. Any ideas?

Comment: Not working for me either version 106.2.2, .NET Standard 2.0.1, Xamarin.Forms 3.0.0

Comment: @Jam I tried 106.3 with explicitly specified proxy and default proxy and it works. The default proxy is only available on Windows as far as I know.

Comment: It's fine on 106.3. Thank you.

Comment: Up and running with proxy and credentials with dotnet core 2.2, using RestSharp 106.6.9

Comment: Contrary to what Alexey says, I don't find that .NET Core 3.1 version of RestSharp picks up the default proxy.

Comment: ...Nothing shows up in Fiddler unless I manually configure it with the code above. .NET Core 3.1 and RestSharp 106.11.4

Comment: ...and there is no longer client.Proxy() so it seems it's now not possible to use a proxy with Restsharp()?

Comment: Please check the migration guide. The `Proxy` property is available in the client options.

Answer (score 0):

use RestClient with HttpClientHandler

```
var proxy = GetWebProxy();//your IWebProxy factory
 var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
 {
     Proxy = proxy,
 };
 using (var dataClient = new RestClient(httpClientHandler))
 {
...
}
```