# RestSharp not using Proxy (Fiddler) in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, restsharp, .net-core-2.0

I've got a **.NET Core 2.0 Console** application that I would like to debug with **Fiddler**, or more precise, the **REST** request made by **RestSharp**.

It seems that **RestSharp** does not take my proxy settings, no matter if it's the system proxy, or a proxy explicitly set.

**RestSharp** version: `106.2.2` (latest as of this writing)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var proxy = new WebProxy("some_non_existing_server", 8888) {BypassProxyOnLocal = false};
    var restSharpClient = new RestClient("http://www.google.ch");
    restSharpClient.Proxy = proxy;
    var request = new RestRequest("/", Method.GET);
    var result = restSharpClient.Execute(request);

    if (!result.IsSuccessful ||
        result.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK ||
        result.ErrorException != null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unexpected response.");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Request successful.");
}
```

Expected result: `Exception` (because proxy server does not exist)

Actual result: `Request successful`

I can see others having difficulties with this as well, but usually the solution involved setting the proxy explicitly like I do in the code above.

Any pointers on getting this to work?

*(if it matters, I'm executing this on Windows 10 x64 with `dotnet.exe <dll name>`)*

```
λ dotnet --info                                                  
.NET Command Line Tools (2.1.105)                                

Product Information:                                             
 Version:            2.1.105                                     
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  141cc8d976                                  

Runtime Environment:                                             
 OS Name:     Windows                                            
 OS Version:  10.0.17134                                         
 OS Platform: Windows                                            
 RID:         win10-x64                                          
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.105\               

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host                        

  Version  : 2.0.7                                               
  Build    : 2d61d0b043915bc948ebf98836fefe9ba942be11
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RestSharp ignoring system proxy (for example Fiddler) on .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47408423/restsharp-ignoring-system-proxy-for-example-fiddler-on-net-core)

Comment: @KobyDouek thanks, the "solution" on the duplicate question is exactly what I use in my question, hence my question :)

Comment: I've got the exact same problem today! This weird timing is making me think it's related to 1803. Are you on Windows 10 and have you updated it?

Comment: @LuisFerrao indeed, I am and I have updated... I've even started debugging RestSharp now :) However "plain old webrequest" does seem to work fine, at least on .NET 4.7.1. (Trying to take .NET Core out of the equation for now)

Comment: @LuisFerrao I have made a PR to RestSharp now, I think it's a bug in their code. https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/pull/1118

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug, which I have fixed upstream with a [Pull request](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/pull/1118).

It is already merged and I guess it will be included in versions of RestSharp after `106.2.2`. So either compile it yourself from GitHub if it is not yet released to NuGet, or use a NuGet version later than `106.2.2`

Comment: Here is the package with your PR merged. Thanks for the fix! https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/106.3.0-alpha0025