# RestSharp request aborted - could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, restsharp

I'm trying to test an API call on my local machine, using RestSharp, with the following code...

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://[API URL]");

        var request = new RestRequest( Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("session", this, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        IRestResponse<SessionOut> response = client.Execute<SessionOut>(request);
        return response.Data.session.id;
```

In `response` I get the an error telling me that the request was aborted because it "could not create SSL/TLS secure channel".

Does this mean I need to try and set up https://localhost instead of http://localhost in order to call APIs at https:// addresses?

**UPDATE**

I have updated my code to the following, as per @Shai_Aharoni's answer below. I am still getting the same error however.

```
        string pathToYourClientCert = Path.Combine( AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "[my certificate file");
        var client = new RestClient("[API URL]/");
        client.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection();
        client.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate(pathToYourClientCert));

        var request = new RestRequest( Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("session", this, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        IRestResponse<SessionOut> response2 = client.Execute<SessionOut>(request);
```

Comment: Is your system have some kind of proxy,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47675172/713789

Comment: No @AnirudhaGupta , just testing straight from localhost to the API.

Comment: Check @Shai's answer, if it doesn't work well, can you test it in Postman and HttpClient, If it show same, you need to have installed that certificate in your machine. that answer should work.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding this to your code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Related resources:

- [Some useful information about setting TLS 1.2 in another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5)

Comment: if you cant find SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 and only have SecurityProtocolType.Tls. consider upgrading from .Net 4.0 to 4.5. or just use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47269609/system-net-securityprotocoltype-tls12-definition-not-found

Answer (score 1):

Well... There are a few steps that you need to complete before you can call you HTTPS endpoint.

1) Make sure that your server supports an HTTPS endpoint (i.e : that the URL https://[APIURL] is reachable.

2) Have a valid server (the api server) certificate installed on the machine that executes the HTTPS call.

3) Add the certificate to your RestSharp client. Similar to something like this:

```
string pathToYourClientCert = "cer/cert.cer";
client.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate(pathToYourClientCert));
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks @Shai_Aharoni, I've added the certificate loading code in, still getting the same error. The certificate was created in IIS and exported using mmc.exe. The website runs (with warning because of self-created certificate) at https://
See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack?tabs=macos

Also add this to your code in MainActivity.cs -> OnCreate -> Before you load your app:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

I had to do both for my API requests to work in Xamarin Forms!

Make sure your CERTIFICATE is not SELF-SIGNED!!!