# Unable to make a GET request with RestSharp.NetCore

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I'm attempting to use RestSharpe.NetCore(v.105.2.3.0) to make a GET request e.g. `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto` in C#.

However, I get a `Error: SecureChannelFailure (Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.)` error with my code below.

```
IRestClient _client;

protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    ...
    var baseurl = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";
    var apiMethod = "ditto";
    var request = new RestRequest(apiMethod, Method.GET);

    this._client = new RestClient();
    this._client.BaseUrl = new Uri(baseurl);
    TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse> taskCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();
    var json = this._client.ExecuteAsync<object>(request, r => taskCompletion.SetResult(r));
    var response = (object)(await taskCompletion.Task);
}
```

Any ideas why and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before making the connection to use TLS1.1 or 1.2 to connect to the site.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

For proxy, add your proxy to the client

```
client.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);
```

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47408423/restsharp-ignoring-system-proxy-for-example-fiddler-on-net-core/47675172) for details

Comment: I've tried setting it to use TLS1.1 and 1.2 above the `ExecuteAsync` method call and I receive the same outcome.

Comment: @bhav You are able to access the url from chrome?

Comment: Yes, I see the JSON response in Chrome.

Comment: Do you use proxy from the network you are running this call from?

Comment: Yes, I use a proxy which might be causing the issue.

Comment: @Bhav You can add the proxy to the client. Updated response with it

Comment: The interface IRestClient doesn't have a definition for Proxy. :s Also, I'm wondering if there's any way to explicitly use my default credentials?